# How to get signal sender type when using multi authorization providers?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-signals, django-socialauth

In my app I am using standard auth module and [social auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) plugin.
I want to detect if user is registering via oauth or standard method

I have function registered to post_save signal:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        key, expires = UserProfile.generate_activation_data()
        return UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance, activation_key=key, key_expires=expires)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

But when user is registered via oauth I would to avoid creating activation data, instead set some field indicated that user is register by oauth.

Could someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [pipeline method](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html) that sets a flag in the user instance, something like this:

```
def created_by_social_auth(user, *args, **kwargs):
    user.by_social_auth = True
```

Also you could check if the user has any `UserSocialAuth` instance releated with:

```
user.social_auth.count()
```